# How can I plot separate maps of data using plt.subplots?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot separate maps for six different time steps of my data set. My code is shown below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter
from cartopy.util import add_cyclic_point
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

#open dataset
myfile = 'gfs20191010.0p25.nc'
fh = Dataset(myfile, mode='r')

#select variables
h5001 = fh.variables['h5'][0:24,:,:]
h5002 = fh.variables['h5'][25:48,:,:]
h5003 = fh.variables['h5'][49:72,:,:]
h5004 = fh.variables['h5'][73:96,:,:]
h5005 = fh.variables['h5'][97:120,:,:]
h5006 = fh.variables['h5'][121:144,:,:]
lats = fh.variables['lat'][:]
lons = fh.variables['lon'][:]

#take mean of 500mb heights for the first 24 hours
day1 = np.mean(h5001,axis=0)
day2 = np.mean(h5002,axis=0)
day3 = np.mean(h5003,axis=0)
day4 = np.mean(h5004,axis=0)
day5 = np.mean(h5005,axis=0)
day6 = np.mean(h5006,axis=0)

fcst_crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

ax0 = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax0.set_extent([230,300,20,90],ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax0.coastlines()
ax0.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)
ax0.add_feature(cfeature.STATES)
ax0.set_title('Mean 500mb Heights (dam)', fontsize=12)
fig = plt.subplot(ax0)

mean1 = fig.contour(lons,lats,day1[0,:,:],levels=60,extend='both',transform=fcst_crs)
mean2 = fig.contour(lons,lats,day2[0,:,:],levels=60,extend='both',transform=fcst_crs)
mean3 = fig.contour(lons,lats,day3[0,:,:],levels=60,extend='both',transform=fcst_crs)
mean4 = fig.contour(lons,lats,day4[0,:,:],levels=60,extend='both',transform=fcst_crs)
mean5 = fig.contour(lons,lats,day5[0,:,:],levels=60,extend='both',transform=fcst_crs)
mean6 = fig.contour(lons,lats,day6[0,:,:],levels=60,extend='both',transform=fcst_crs)

fig1 = plt.contour(mean1, colors = 'black')
fig2 = plt.contour(mean2, colors = 'black')
fig3 = plt.contour(mean3, colors = 'black')
fig4 = plt.contour(mean4, colors = 'black')
fig5 = plt.contour(mean5, colors = 'black')
fig6 = plt.contour(mean6, colors = 'black')

plt.savefig('500mbHGT.png')
plt.show(fig1)
plt.show(fig2)
plt.show(fig3)
plt.show(fig4)
plt.show(fig5)
plt.show(fig6)
```

When I run the above code, all of my data plots on to one map. I have tried to make several adjustments based on the documentation provided here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html
I've also tried following multiple examples of code using subplots for different uses. I am still unable to get separate maps plotted, but from what I understand, subplots is the way I should approach this problem, so hopefully I am on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

By generating the subplots at the beginning with plt.subplots, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)

axes[0].set_title("Hammer projection")
map = Basemap(projection='hammer', lon_0 = 10, lat_0 = 50,           ax=axes[0])

map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
map.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
map.drawcoastlines()

axes[1].set_title("Robinson projection")
map = Basemap(projection='robin', lon_0 = 10, lat_0 = 50,        ax=axes[1])

map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
map.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
map.drawcoastlines()

plt.show()
```